# Muting audio with amixer, there is a chance that audio channels become unbalanced?

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, pulseaudio, amixer

I have 3 commands set as keyboard shortcuts:

```
amixer -D pulse set Master 1+ toggle
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
```

If I mash the 3 keys that trigger the above 3 commands very fast so that Pulseaudio output is muted, up in volume, and down in volume all around the same time, the "output audio device audio levels" become unbalanced.

While this might sound like a niche case, it seems to happen randomly with regular use of the computer, and changing volume (the above is the most basic reproduction case). Example below of the reproduction:

[image]

**Is there any reason that the above 3 commands would affect the balance levels of the audio device?**

It seems very strange that the 3 above commands would affect it, or maybe I'm using the wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I believe was having two sets of volume hotkeys mixed with volume buttons. With only one set of hotkeys, it's fixed.